# Why docker image is running using some random user, even after providing --user?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run docker image using under my user name, but when I checked it was running under some random user name(awoodard). And now I am not even able to kill it since as per the error, my user is not a part of sudoers. I am a novice in this field and not aware of such technicalities. May I request you to help me with this?

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.1-devel-ubuntu20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    apt-utils \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
    wget \
    build-essential \
    pkg-config \
    vim

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME /app

CMD bash
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh


ENV user gauravs
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash ${user} \
       && chown -R ${user}:${user} /app \
       && adduser ${user} sudo
RUN echo "%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers
USER ${user}


ENV PATH=/home/${user}/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN sudo chmod 777 -R /app
RUN sudo chmod 777 /home/${user}

RUN sudo apt-get  -y --no-install-recommends install python3-dev
RUN sudo apt-get  -y --no-install-recommends install  python3-pip
```

When I used ps aux|grep

```
awoodard 2805117 8778  0.6 27876664 5175500 ?    Rsl  10:31 8783:54 python3 main.py --gpu_num 1
gauravs  2808325  0.0  0.0   9032  2708 pts/1    S+   12:11   0:00 grep --color=auto 2805117
```

Comment: The host and container have separate `/etc/passwd` files, so you're seeing whatever host user matches the numeric user ID inside the container.  It's not usually a practical problem.

Comment: Thanks, @David Maze, for responding. May I request you to explain this in little detail? I am not able to get what you said?

Comment: I posted a slightly longer explanation of @DavidMaze's comment as an answer (it was a bit too long to post as comment  :) hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @theJeztah. Appreciated the time you put in. May I request you to tell me how can I avoid such confusion?

Comment: I don't think there's much that can be done, other than using the `n` option on `ps` to view numeric ID's. It's how things work; namespaces (which is what containers use) isolate a process, and provide a "different view on the world". So processes running in different namespaces (including something running on the "host", outside of the container) will have a different view of "the world". You can use `docker top` to view processes in a specific container

Comment: I resolved it by removing ENV user gauravs and replacing "${user}" with the "user."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux users and groups use numeric ID's (UID and GID). As numeric IDs are not very convenient to use, you can also "create" a user (or group). Creating a user/group associates a name with a numeric ID (along with some other metadata, such as "the default shell" and the user's home-directory, etc.). User names are usually stored within `/etc/passwd` (the name of that file is a bit poorly chosen: there's no passwords in there).
Commands, such as `ps` use the information in `/etc/passwd` to lookup the user's name. So when it finds a process running as UID 1000, it looks up the name associated with UID 1000, and shows that.

When you create a user within the container, the first available (not yet associated with a name) numeric UID is picked, and the user's name is written to `/etc/passwd` (within the container).

If you run `ps` within the container, it looks up that name in the `/etc/passwd` file within the container, but when you run `ps` from outside the container, it looks in `/etc/passwd` *on the host*. If the host happens to have an entry in `/etc/passwd` for the same UID that's running in the container (more accurately: in the container's namespace), it will show the name for that UID it found on the host, which may be a different name than you used within the container.

If you use the `n` option on `ps`, the command skips looking up user (and group) names, showing their numeric UID/GID instead (see [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)), doing so should show the same UID/GID when run inside and outside the container.

It's worth noting that, while creating a user is usually needed on a Linux *machine* (to configure the shell, home-directory, password etc), containers are not VM's, and the `USER` instruction in a Dockerfile (and `--user` flag on `docker run`) does not start a new user *session* (it does not "log in" the user), instead only instructs Docker (or other container runtimes) to run the process with the given user and group.

Because of that, it's also possible to run a process as a different user, without actually "creating" a user, for example:

```sh
docker run --rm --user=123:456 busybox id
uid=123 gid=456
```

If no entry exists in `/etc/passwd` for that user, the `id` command shows the numeric IDs (as can be seen above), and when using an existing user, it shows the names associated:

```sh
docker run --rm --user=1:1 busybox id
uid=1(daemon) gid=1(daemon)
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I had a very sketchy user I created long ago for doing MITM attacks on my phone. Seeing a bunch of docker processes running as my mitmuser was definite a pretty jarring as I worried I had done something wrong.